# Multiple Plot Display (ggplot only display the last chart when using loop)

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a set of plots that I would like to display using an iterated function. Unfortunately, when I place those plots into a list and try to call those plots again, only the last plot is being displayed.

Attached is my code if you guys can help me.

```
`Production<-read.csv("Production.csv")
dataset<-read.csv("Try.csv")
Q<-list()
for (i in 1:2){
Hourly<-loadprofile[,1]
Average<-loadprofile[,2+i-1]
Max<-loadprofile[,368+i-1]
Min<-loadprofile[,734+i-1]
hour<-dataset[,3*i-2]
Company<-dataset[,3*i-1]
Production<-dataset[,3*i]
Q[[length(Q)+1+i]]<-ggplot()+
geom_bar(data=dataset,aes(x=hour, y=Production,
fill=Company),stat="identity") +
geom_line(data=production,aes(x=Hourly, y=Average),stat="identity")+
geom_ribbon(data=production,aes(x=Hourly,ymin=Min, ymax=Max), alpha=0.5,
fill='blue', stat="identity")+
ggtitle("1/1/2017")
}
```

I have 60 different graphs but I using a two iteration loop for now to test it out. When I enter the command Q[[2]], only the second graph appear and not the first. I am trying to display these graphs into one page and would appreciate any help.

Comment: the question is not very clear. What are you trying to do ? Visualizing more than one plot in the same "page" ? If so, this is not going to work: Q[[2]] is one plot, so obviously you see just that. You can have a look at `grid.arrange`  in package `gridExtra`. But I'm not sure this is what you want....

Comment: Yes Lorenzo. I am trying to visualize multiple plots in one page. 
I understand that I can use grid.arrange. But before I even do that, I am trying to find a way to store the multiple plots that i generated into a list. So I can recall them.

Comment: Ideally, I am thinking that i can store the first plot into Q[1] and the second plot into Q[2], and so on and then use grid.arrange to display my graphs in one page.

Comment: sorry, what happens if you call `Q[[1]]`

Comment: Right now it's Null. I mean when I run the loop with print(plot) within the loop. I have the first plot appear and the second plot appear immediately after. I am now trying to get them onto the same page side by side.

Comment: This: `Q[[length(Q)+1+i]]` should be: `Q[[i]]`  Currently you probably have something in Q[[4]]

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that as well. And the Q[1] chart is the Q[2]  chart.  So I still cant recall the first chart using Q[1]

Comment: if you just loop on "i in 1:1" what do you get ? By the way: besides you current problem the Q[[length(Q...   is defintely wrong. You'll assign to positions 2,5,8... or something like that.

Comment: If I loop on "i in 1:1", then my Q[1] based on the Q[[i]] formula is the first chart. So it seems that when i loop it more than once, the second chart replaces the first, and both Q[1] and Q[2] has the second chart.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some problems elsewhere, because as you can see from this:

```
a = (1:10)
b = (1:10)

df1 = data.frame(a=a,b=b)
df2 = data.frame(a=b,b=-a)

Q = list()

for (i in 1:2){

  if (i == 1) {Qi = ggplot(df1, aes(x = a, y = b))+geom_point()}
  if (i == 2 ) {Qi = ggplot(df2, aes(x = a, y = b))+geom_point()}

  Q[[i]] = Qi

}

Q[[1]]
Q[[2]]
```

actually works and prints two different graphs. The "indexing" in your function seems a bit confusing (e.g., `[,368+i-1]`, `[,3*i-2]]`, so maybe you have problems there.

Comment: Apparently, I just had to change my aes to aes_string